# Pass complex Razor expression to helper

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

Ho do you pass a line of complex Razor into a helper parameter? This is the best I could come up with, but it can't be right:

```
@helper Bold(MvcHtmlString fragment){
    <b>@fragment</b>
}

@*
helper containing the fragment, otherwise redundant
*@
@helper Status(){
    @Model.In@:/@Model.Total processed
}

@Bold(new MvcHtmlString(Status().ToHtmlString()))
```

**EDIT**: I know `Status` is better done in the ViewModel in most cases.

Answer (score 0):

View Helpers are static by nature and do not have access to the page model, if you need to generate a `Status` message, you better do it in the View-Model:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public int In {get;set;}
    public int Total {get;set;}

    public string GetStatus()
    {
        return In + "/" + Total + " processed";
    }
}
```

And your helper would look like:

```
@helper Bold(string fragment){
    <b>@fragment</b>
}
```

Usage:

```
@Bold(Model.GetStatus())
```

---

Alternatively, you can pass `In` and `Total` as an argument to the Helper:

```
@helper Bold(string fragment){
    <b>@fragment</b>
}

@helper GetTotal(int _in, int _total)
{
    @_in @:/ @_total processed
}
```

Usage:

```
@Bold(GetTotal(Model.In, Model.Total).ToString())
```

Comment: "View Helpers are static by nature". true, but it should still be possible to generate the Razor by inlining `Status` somehow, no?